# how to configure typescript when using nodejs ECMAScript Modules

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

When using node with `"type": "module",` (still experimental, but works) you can literally `import foo from 'foo';` when `foo` has `module.exports = ...`.

How should typescript be configured when doing this?

When having `"module": "commonjs",` in the `tsconfig.json` then `import foo from 'foo';` works as expected. However when doing `"module": "es2015",` then `tsc` will throw

> Cannot find module 'foo'.

I'm not authoring `foo`, so I can not change anything about this. For now using `"module": "commonjs",` to check types and then using `babel` to remove types seems to work as a workaround.

Comment: You need to specify `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` also set `"moduleResolution": "node" `

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect `"module": "es2015"` to have the default `moduleResolution: 'classic'`.

Comment: The reason is that module resolution is not really part of any module format specification. They are orthogonal concepts. TS defaults to node resolution for common JS because the two evolved together and are almost always used in tandem. ES2015 modules don't have that history. Neither module resolution scheme is natural to ES modules.  Of course, the tools have to use something or other. This is the flaw of the maximally minimal approach tc39 takes.